# ipkg not working properly in dd-wrt

Tags: router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, ipkg

I first tried to install `httping`, so I can ping websites. I got this error:

```
ERROR: File not found: //usr/local/lib/ipkg/lists/whiterussian
       You probably want to run `ipkg update'
ERROR: File not found: //usr/local/lib/ipkg/lists/non-free
       You probably want to run `ipkg update'
ERROR: File not found: //usr/local/lib/ipkg/lists/backports
       You probably want to run `ipkg update'
/bin/ipkg: line 1184: sort: not found
/bin/ipkg: line 1184: can't open /jffs//usr/local/lib/ipkg/status: no such file
/bin/ipkg: line 1184: can't create /jffs//usr/local/lib/ipkg/status: nonexistent directory
/bin/ipkg: line 1184: can't create /jffs//usr/local/lib/ipkg/status: nonexistent directory
ERROR: File not found: //usr/local/lib/ipkg/lists/whiterussian
       You probably want to run `ipkg update'
ERROR: File not found: //usr/local/lib/ipkg/lists/non-free
       You probably want to run `ipkg update'
ERROR: File not found: //usr/local/lib/ipkg/lists/backports
       You probably want to run `ipkg update'
ipkg_get_install: ERROR: Cannot find package httping in //usr/local/lib/ipkg/lists
ipkg_get_install:        Check the spelling and maybe run `ipkg update'.
/bin/ipkg: line 1184: can't open /jffs//usr/local/lib/ipkg/status: no such file
```

So, I tried running `ipkg update`. It takes less than a fourth of a second to finish (which is surprising), and then I run `ipkg install httping` again with the same issue. Then, I decided to run `ipkg list`, and I get this:

```
ERROR: File not found: //usr/local/lib/ipkg/lists/whiterussian
       You probably want to run `ipkg update'
ERROR: File not found: //usr/local/lib/ipkg/lists/non-free
       You probably want to run `ipkg update'
ERROR: File not found: //usr/local/lib/ipkg/lists/backports
       You probably want to run `ipkg update'
```

So, how can I fix this?

*Note: I have a Netgear WNDR4300.*

*Update: I tried running `bash` and `/bin/bash`, and I get `-sh: /bin/bash: not found`. Something really weird is going on here.*

Comment: The default DD-WRT builds use Busybox's Ash, a lightweight shell, similar but less-function filled than Bash. /Bin/Bash is symlinked to /opt/bin/bash and needs to be installed.

Comment: @cde Well, how can I install it then?

Comment: What Build are you running?